# When does $P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n!}{n^n}\cdot x^n}$ with $x\in \mathbb{C}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

When does $P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n!}{n^n}\cdot x^n}$ with $x\in \mathbb{C}$ converge?

**My Attempt:**$$\bigg |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\bigg |=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\to e$$ So it converges for $|x|<e$. Now I wanted to check wheter the series converges for $e$ or $-e$.

I fail to either prove the divergence or convergence. Can you help?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: No Stirling allowed!

Answer (score 3):

In fact $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<e$, and this can be used to prove by induction that $\left|e^n\frac{n!}{n^n}\right|>1$ for all $n\geq 1$. Thus when $|x|=e$ the terms don't tend to zero and it can't converge.

Comment: hmm, im not that happy with that proof... Is there a way to prove it via the direct comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

An approach without Stirling, for $x=-e$ you can just bound $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ by 1.

For $x=e$, we know that $e=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ that sequence is increasing, so 
$$e^n\geq \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}$$
So, we have that:

$$\frac{n! e^n}{n^n}\geq \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}>1$$ so series diverge

Comment: Could I use $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_{n})^{1/n}\leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_{n})^{1/n}\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ for $a_n:=n!$?